# wget, curl commands accept partial filenames

Tags: curl, wget

I am trying to download a file **hpraid.tar.gz** from a remote server using

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar

curl -O http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar
```

Even though the **.gz** extension is omitted in the filename part, yet the file gets downloaded by both **wget** and **curl**
This partial filename match without any wildcard baffles me.

Is there anyway I can force **wget** and **curl** to match the complete filename?

Comment: the problem isn't the client (wget/curl), the problem is the server. the server does the autocomplete/wildcard match/whatever.  you might get more clues by giving `-v` to curl, or checking the server logs, but the real cause  is almost certainly in the server configuration.

Comment: Got a workaround options `-r` and `--accept`. Now the command `wget --no-check-certificate -r --accept="hpraid.tar.gz" http://xx.xx.xx/hpraid.tar.gz`